# Py3.5 subprocess.run unexpected kwarg 'stderr'

Tags: python, django, subprocess, python-import, python-3.5

I recently used Python3.5 `subprocess.run` in a Django==1.9.1 project. The app was called `contest` and the two files of interest were:

- contest/compat.py
- contest/utils.py

Now, compat.py has:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 5):
    from subprocess import (run,
                            PIPE,
                            TimeoutExpired)
    print('V> 3.5')

else:

    from subprocess import (PIPE,
                            Popen,
                            TimeoutExpired,
                            CalledProcessError,
                            CompletedProcess)

    def run(*popenargs, input=None, timeout=None, check=False, **kwargs):
        '''Python3.5 subprocess code copied here'''
        return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    print('V NOT > 3.5')
```

contest/utils.py contains

```
from contest.compat import (run,
                            PIPE,
                            TimeoutExpired)

def some_function(*args, **kwargs):
        p = run(cmd,
                timeout=timeout,
                stderr=PIPE,
                stdout=PIPE,
                shell=True)
```

Now when I run this bit of code on it's own with py3.5 it runs fine. When it is run inside of the Django test server (also on py3.5) and a model's method  calls this utility `some_function` an error is displayed to the effect:

`TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stderr'`

Why does this happen?

Comment: show the complete traceback. Add debug output, to make sure `subprocess.run()` is used (e.g., add `help(run)`)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can no longer reproduce this issue I assume something was wrong with my environment.